# Using Formula to determine Shift from Time data

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have a column of time data formatted like this: `hh:mm:ss`

I want to make an IF statement that returns 1, 2 or 3 corresponding to first, second or third shift if the times fall between certain values.

```
=IF(AND(E50>8,0,0,E50<16,0,0),"First",(IF(AND(E50>=16,0,0,E50<24,0,0), "Second", "Third")))
```

That's what it looks like now, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your three shift start times in cells and reference them, it is as simple as this:

```
=IF(AND(D13>=$D$11, D13<$E$11),"First",IF(AND(D13>=$E$11,D13<$F$11),"Second", "Third"))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked too, what If my shift start times were not exactly 8 on the dot, but more like 7:10:00 A.M. to 3:10:00 P.M. or 7:10:00 to 15:10:00

Comment: @J.A. Just change the 8/16/24 in my formula that I borrowed from your formula.

Comment: Should `HOUR(E50)>8` be `HOUR(E50)>=8` ? Is `HOUR(E50)<24` necessary?

Comment: I get an error when I put my times in where  you have 8,16,24 and Excel changes the order in which I entered the times. So I used commas instead of semicolons to separate, 
Like so:
>=IF(AND(HOUR(E50)>7,10, HOUR(E50)<15,10),"First",IF(AND(HOUR(E50)>=15,10,HOUR(E50)<23,10),"Second", "Third"))

Comment: @J.A. If you are going to get into minutes, you have to use `=minute(cell)`.  I'll edit my post to make it easier.

Comment: @Chrismas007 if the time is **just** time without a date, then your formula will work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907) with [HOUR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HOUR-function-a3afa879-86cb-4339-b1b5-2dd2d7310ac7). You should account for all possible results.

```
=choose(hour(e50)/8+1, "third", "first", "second")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a short formula:

```
=CHOOSE(INT(1+MOD(E50,1)*3),"Third","First","Second")
```

will do what you want.

If the time is just time (no date) then

```
=CHOOSE(INT(1+E50*3),"Third","First","Second")
```

also will do.

Also this formulas should be very fast ;)

**EDIT**

To make it completely "variable" you would need something like this (timetable is at I51:J53 ascendenting order):

```
=INDEX($J$51:$J$53,COUNTIF($I$51:$I$53,"<="&MOD(E50,1))+IF(COUNTIF($I$51:$I$53,">"&MOD(E50,1))=3,3))
```

It would look like this:

[image]

Note: If you split up the shift which goes from prior 0:00 to past 0:00 so the table would look like:

```
12:00 AM | Third
06:01 AM | First
12:22 PM | Second
10:54 PM | Third
```

then you can skip the formula to:

```
=INDEX($J$51:$J$54,COUNTIF($I$51:$I$54,"<="&MOD(E50,1)))
```

because `+IF(COUNTIF($I$51:$I$53,">"&MOD(E50,1))=3,3)` is only for the case nothing is found (which would be the last shift)...

Comment: Darn it! I took the time to include an image!

Comment: That worked, but can you explain how it did that, I'm a little amazed.

Comment: @Jeeped And a link... and a description ;P ...still, theoretically we are both wrong... the first shift falls **between** 8 and 16... this excludes 8 and 16 itself... By the question as it is, something like `=IF(MOD(E50,1)>=2/3,"Second",IF(MOD(E50,1)>1/3,"First","Third"))` would be correct...

Comment: @J.A. time is just a number from 0 to 1 (1 itself would be 0:00 again). by using `MOD(E50,1)` I clear out the date to just get the time. The `*3` makes it that 0:00-8:00 will be 0 to 1, 8:00-16:00 will be 1 to 2 and 16:00-24:00 will be 2 to 3. the `INT(...)` makes it that the number is just 0 for the first option, 1 for the second and 2 for the third. `Choose(...)` picks the part depending on the first value (for that reason the `+1`)... by using the "Evaluate Formula"-function you can see what it does pretty good ;)

Comment: This evaluates it correctly if my shifts follow standard divisions of 8/16/24; how can I modify it to work for shift divisions like: (7:10-15:10), (15:10-23:10), (23:10-7:10) being shifts (1,2,3) respectively.

Comment: I think my If statement is much less complicated now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the simplest way to convert time into 3 shifts. The plus 1 allows for excel returning midnight to 00:59 as 0. (so in the formula below, the first six results of the choose function are `"C"` referring to night shift, then at 6am the shift changes to `"A"` day shift. and so on. `"R3"` is the cell i had the time in.

```
=CHOOSE(HOUR(R3)+1, "C", "C", "C", "C","C","C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C")
```